# resistor package size

Tags: resistors, pcb-design, packages

I am using EasyEDA to design some PCBs, and I am trying to figure out what package to use for your basic 1/4w resistor. The options are-

- R-Alial-0.3
- R-Alial-0.4
- R-Alial-0.5
- R-Alial-0.6
- R-Alial-0.8
- R-Alial-1.0
- R-Alial-1.2
  Which one is correct? Thanks!

Comment: What’s the wire diameter of the resistors you’ll be using?

Comment: R-Alial-0.4 is for 1/4W resistors and R-Alial-0.5 is for 1/2W, so you can use it too.

Comment: Also, try 0207/10 footprint as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct footprint is the one that your part will conveniently fit into.

I'd guess that the numbers in those footprint names give the distance between pads in inches, and that "Alial" is a typo for "Axial". Based on those guesses, I would use R-Axial-0.4 for 1/4 watt resistors.

Footprint names will vary widely between different PCB programs, and will also depend on the preference of the user.

Place a possible footprint on a board, or look at it in the footprint editor, to determine pad spacing, hole and pad sizes, and other details to see if it meets your requirements.